# Detect closing of a third party popup with browser x button

Tags: javascript, popup

My application has a requirement to call a third party javascript SDK, which inturn opens a popup with that third party domain which is different than my parent site. I am not calling window.open() to open that popup. Is there a way, that I can now detect the closing event of that third party popup when user clicks [x] button on the popup window (not main window). I tried below, but looks like these doesn't work for popups. Can you please help me out..

```
$(window).on('unload', function(){
    alert("unload");
});


$(window).bind("onunload", function() { 
    return "Do you really want to close?"; 
});

$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
    --- do something ---
});
```

Comment: How did you resolve the issue?